# Can I get the request url from a RestClientResponseException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling

I have a rest API where we call other rest API and I need to return an exception with a code for each  error and endpoint called. My idea is to make the code the `httpStatus` + " - " + endpoint called but I'm unable to find where I could find that on my `ControllerAdvice`. Is it possible to get the request URL from a `RestClientException` or a `RestClientResponseException`?

I've tried to use `HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()` but I get the endpoint of the main request, not the endpoint to where the request that caused the exception.